# date issue - string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I am trying the below code: and getting an error:

> string indices must be integers

```
date_n = "2020-03-27"
type(date_n)
# output - str

from datetime import datetime
pro = datetime.strptime(date_n['pro'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

getting an error:

```
>    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bfea650fe110> in <module>
  1 from datetime import datetime
----> 2 pro = datetime.strptime(date_n['pro'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? and what is 'pro' here/

Comment: why `pro` why? :P `datetime.strptime(date_n,'%Y-%m-%d').date()`. date_n is string and not list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to parse a date (which is the purpose of [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)), you can simply use `date_n` as a first argument, it already matches your format `%Y-%m-%d`

```
date_n = "2020-03-27"
print(type(date_n))

from datetime import datetime
pro = datetime.strptime(date_n,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
print(pro)
```

Comment: i have an issue to convert an using .date() - this is the exact issue.

Comment: All 3 answers suggested the same fix. Are you still having problems after applyingnit? If so, update the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `date_n['trxn']` is problematic - this would be the expression for slicing a string.

Your code should work perfectly fine if you just change the line

`pro= datetime.strptime(date_n['pro'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()`

to

`pro= datetime.strptime(date_n,'%Y-%m-%d').date()`.

Answer (score 1):

date_n is still a list (under the hood) because it's a string.
so date_n[0] is the first character, or "2". date_n[1] = 0... etc...

```
pro = datetime.strptime(date_n,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

This should work and give you your datetime.

edit: `pro = datetime.strptime(date_n,'%Y-%m-%d').date()` if you just want the date